# Is there syntax for watching multiple collections together in a single `onUpdate`?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.eventOnUpdate = functions.firestore //
    .document('collection') //
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
        // code here
    })
```

I have multiple collections and subcollections, I need to watch for updates to them in Cloud Functions, to make writes elsewhere. I've scaffolded similar to above.

Am I relegated to defining each onUpdate separately and having them call an external JS function?

Or is there a syntax to watching a group of collections under a single onUpdate?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen In 12 years of StackOverflow, this is the first edit to one of my posts that was substantive and made the question more clear. **Thank you.**

Comment: I misunderstood the question initially, and posted a useless answer based on that. Always good to prevent others from hitting the same confusion. 

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions triggered by Firestore always listen to collections as a specific path. So you can listen for the `subcollection` of every root document with:

```
exports.eventOnUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document('rootcollection/{rootdocid}/subcollection/{subdocid}')
    .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {
        // code here
    })
```

There's no way to listen across an entire branch though: so you can't listen for all writes to all root documents and all subcollections under it. Whenever I need something like that, I put a field (e.g. `lastUpdatedRecursively`) in the parent document, and then listen for updates to that document/collection.